# Looking for scientific papers about lotteries

Tags: sequences-and-series, number-theory, stochastic-processes, algorithms, game-theory

Do you know any paper focusing on the statistical science and math behind lottery and number guessing games? I am creating a new one, where the winning numbers are known in advance, and the gain is known in advance: it is a function of the distance between your guess and the winning number.

I created what I believe is a new system (see my article [New Stock Trading and Lottery Game Rooted in Deep Math](https://www.datasciencecentral.com/profiles/blogs/data-science-foundations-for-a-new-stock-market)), but could not find any related papers that I can cite. My system is based on number theory and stochastic processes.